# No ARCH effect in some series in the data set?

Tags: time-series, arima, autocorrelation, residuals, garch

Of the 60 series in my dataset, 26 don't exhibit an ARCH effect. I have first fitted an ARIMA model (`auto.arima()` in R) and tested it's squared residuals for autocorrelation using a Ljung-Box test (`Box.test()` in R).

26 series do not have an ARCH effect. Can I proceed with multivariate GARCH analysis using all series or should I exclude these series from further analysis?

Comment: The main idea of using a multivariate GARCH is to both capture time-varying volatility and correlation between assets. In theory you can have a multivariate GARCH model, where some of the volatility processes are constant. If your application portfolio optimization I do not think you should remove the assets.

Comment: Thanks, Johan. Yes, portfolio optimization is what I will be heading to after measuring time-varying correlations between series in my dataset.

Comment: Yes you may, then perform backward selection.

Comment: @akkp, backwards selection is almost always a bad idea. To understand further, it may help to see my answer here: [Algorithms for automatic model selection](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/20856/7290).